# convert relative symbolic links to absolute symbolic links

Tags: bash

How can I convert relative symbolic links to absolute symbolic links recursively in bash?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
ln -sf "$(readlink -f "$link")" "$link"
```

Comment: +1, didn't know about the canonicalization options to readlink!

Comment: You can do this for all symbolic links under the current working directory using: `find ./ -type l -execdir bash -c 'ln -sfn "$(readlink -f "$0")" "$0"' {} \;`

Comment: For symlinks pointing to directories this fails: it creates new symlinks with the same name inside the directory (e.g. for a symlink foo -> ../foo you get foo/foo -> /abs/path/to/foo).

Comment: The OSX and some BSD versions of `readlink` do not support the `-f` switch. `-f` is specific to GNU readlink. It can be installed on OSX via `brew install coreutils` which will make it available as `greadlink`.

Comment: @MariusGedminas If you add -T (--no-target-directories) as an argument to ln, then it will succeed.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case somebody looking for reverse operation: conversion from absolute links to relative:

Using python:

```
find . -lname "`pwd`*" -exec sh -c 'ln -snvf `python -c "from os.path import *; print relpath(\"$(readlink {})\",dirname(\"{}\"))"` {}' \;
```

Using only bash and sed:

```
find . -lname "`pwd`/*" -depth 1 -exec sh -c 'ln -snvf `echo $(readlink {}) | sed "s|\`pwd\`|.|"` {}' \;
find . -lname "`pwd`/*" -depth 2 -exec sh -c 'ln -snvf `echo $(readlink {}) | sed "s|\`pwd\`|..|"` {}' \;
find . -lname "`pwd`/*" -depth 3 -exec sh -c 'ln -snvf `echo $(readlink {}) | sed "s|\`pwd\`|../..|"` {}' \;
etc....
```

This would convert all absolute links in the subdirectories to a relative ones.

Comment: There is also a symlinks package available: `symlinks -a /path/to/modify` http://linux.die.net/man/8/symlinks

Comment: Unfortunately it's not available on some OSes. ;(

Comment: You can download the Debian source file and just run `gcc symlinks.c -o /usr/local/bin/symlinks`. Doesn't seem to depend on anything else. http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/s/symlinks/symlinks_1.4.orig.tar.gz

Comment: * For other Linux distributions. :)