# convert symbolic link with relative path to absolute using find

Tags: shell

I want to do convert all the symbolic links i find to be absolute path so that i can move the entire dir around.  So i thought doing something like [convert relative symbolic links to absolute symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187210/convert-relative-symbolic-links-to-absolute-symbolic-links) , using find would work.

`find some_path -type l -exec ln -sf "$(readlink -f "{}")" "{}" \;`

but this didn't work I expected.  looking for the reason, I found that:

`find some_path -type l -exec readlink -f "{}" \;`

the above returns absolute path of the link being found but

`find some_path -type l -exec echo "$(readlink -f "{}")" \;`

this generates wrong path.   so command expansion with find -exec is not working correctly.  what shall I do?   I tried `find ... | xargs -i`, but there as well, once I tried to use readlink to substitute linkname to abspath and keep it as variable, it got garbled.

Comment: To make a directory moveable you need to convert all links that point outside the directory to absolute and all links that point in the directory to relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find some_path -type l | while read LINK ; do 
  ln -sf "$(readlink -f "$LINK")" "$LINK"
done
```

You could easily concatenate this to one line.